# how can I only authorize access to data in snowflake the user can access has his username in it?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**What I want**

example I created a new user having
`username = ali433210` in
snowflake database which has many tables and records with the username ali433210 and I only want him to access only the records having username ali433210.

**What I have done and working**

The approach I followed, I am creating views where username = ali433210 for each table and give him access to only those views.

**What I am looking for?**
Is there anyway to automate the above process, or Is there any better approach to restrict without creating views?

table example 1

```
username  subject1
ali433210  CS1
ali22111   CS2
ali433210  MS1
ali22111   CS4
```

table example 2

```
username   age
ali433210  55
ali22111   12
ali433210  43
ali433210  44
ali433210  33
```

Comment: Have a look at row access policies: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-row-intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A row access policy would work (requires Enterprise Edition or higher):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY match_username
AS (col_with_username varchar) RETURNS BOOLEAN ->
  col_with_username = CURRENT_USER()
;
```

Then you apply that policy to any table that should be filtered, and those table will only show the rows with a matching username.

You'll also want to add some role logic to that policy, to enable some roles to see all rows in those tables.

If you don't have access to the enterprise edition, you could also leverage secure views and `CURRENT_USER()`:

```sql
create table a_table
as
select 1 x, 'FELIPE' user_col
union all
select 2, 'SAYED'
;

create secure view filter_by_username
as
select *
from a_table
where user_col = CURRENT_USER()
;

select *
from filter_by_username;
```